# Tem como trabalhar com array no SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, array, sql-server, script

Olá amigos colaboradores...

Estou com um servidor que possui mais de 100 bancos, e a maioria são da mesma estrutura.

Gostaria de criar uma função, procedure ou seja lá o que for. Que pudesse agilizar minha manutenção.

Pensei aqui na possibilidade de ter um array com nome destes bancos, e de ler esse array e disparando os comandos necessários.

Ainda não obtive resultados, veja o seguinte código a ver se me entendem:

```
DECLARE @arrayMinhaBase = [
    0 -> "nomeDoBancoUm",
    1 -> "nomeDoBancoDois",
    2 -> "nomeDoBancoTres",
    3 -> "nomeDoBancoQuatro",
    4 -> "nomeDoBancoCinco",
    5 -> "nomeDoBancoSeis"
    -- etc -> "nomeDoBanco"
];

DECLARE @totalBase int = 1; 
DECLARE @chave int; 

SET @chave = 0;
SET @totalBase = count(@arrayMinhaBase);

WHILE @chave <= @totalBase
  BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM @arrayMinhaBase[$chave].nomeDaTabela;

  END
```

Bom, o que eu conseguir o mais próximo de agilizar este processo, fico grato.
O Exemplo acima eu usei um select, mas na maioria das vezes é pra rodar um alter table ou update.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada na sp_msforeachdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Crie uma variável do tipo tabela para armazenar o nome dos bancos;
- Insira os nomes dos bancos que deseja selecionar valores;
- Percorra a tabela com um cursor;
- Utilize a função `EXEC` para executar um `VARCHAR` como comando.

---

```
DECLARE @bancos TABLE(nome VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @banco VARCHAR(100);

INSERT INTO @bancos VALUES('Loteria'),
                          ('Vehicle');

DECLARE cursor_banco CURSOR FOR   
  SELECT b.nome
    FROM @bancos b;
OPEN cursor_banco;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_banco
INTO @banco;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
  EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @banco + '.dbo.tabela');

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_banco   
  INTO @banco;
END   
CLOSE cursor_banco;  
DEALLOCATE cursor_banco;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

P.S. Não sei como fechar o tópico, a pergunta. Marcar como resolvido etc...

Comment: @PedroHsa basta clicar no V verde ao lado da minha resposta

Comment: @PedroHsa os 100 bancos de dados são seus? A lista de bancos que é mostrado no `SSMS`são somente os seus e você tem acesso ao banco de dados `master`?

Comment: São sim eu cheguei a ver funções nativas do SQL Server mas nenhuma me ajudou. Na idéia ai do @Sorack deu certo. Consegui organizar meu servidor.